# CollectionView with Filter not updating after ObservableCollection<T>.Move

Tags: .net, wpf

Using .NET 3.5, I'm finding that a CollectionView with a filter doesn't update when the underlying ObservableCollection(T) has items moved using ObservableCollection(T).Move.  As a sanity check, I started with a simple project, one of Bea Stollnitz' from this page:  http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31.  The actual project can be downloaded here:  bea.stollnitz.com/files/28/FilterSample.zip.  If you go into her Window1.xaml file and add a button like this:

```
<StackPanel>

         <Button Content="Blah" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

and then add the click handler like this:

```
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
GreekGods src1 = this.Resources["src1"] as GreekGods;
         src1.Move(0, 1);
      }
```

You'll find that pressing the button does not result in any change in the window.  However, if you comment out the line of code in her constructor:

```
     collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterOutA);
```

and then press the button, you'll see the two top elements swap position.

So what am I missing?  Is this a bug, or does CollectionView just lose this functionality when you apply a filter?  I can understand if you've got the CollectionView sorted, then changing the underlying order wouldn't change the CollectionView's order, but that's not true here.  Shouldn't just having a Filter on the CollectionView continue to show the underlying ObservableCollection's order and update as it changes?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug and is working perfectly.  See, in that example, here's the order of items in the source collection:

[0] Venus
[1] Apollo
[2] Mars

Now, if you apply "FilterOutA", "Apollo" will be removed and thus the listbox will just show:

[0] Venus
[1] Apollo <-Filtered out
[2] Mars

Given this, calling `src1.Move(0,1)` will essentially move "Venus" to index 1.  Thus, in the filtered collection, it will appear like nothing changed.

[0] Apollo <-Filtered out
 
[1] Venus 
[2] Mars

The thing to note here is that the Move() method works on the original collection and not the filtered one.

Try changing the move operation to `src1.Move(0,2)`, and you'll see the UI update.

Comment: I'm sure you're right on this, but unfortunately I think this is a case of my example not being constructed like my real case.  I'm pretty sure I checked the condition you're referring to in my real case and it didn't apply.  I just got ahead of myself when I found this example also appeared not to work.  I'll go back to the drawing board and see if I can put together a better example (and reconfirm this isn't what's happening in my real case).  Thanks!